# Сравнивание однотипных элементов списка друг с другом в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы

Дан список:

```
list = [220.32, 205.1, 204.6, 203.2, 203.75, 203.25, 203.75, 203.5]
```

Необходимо сравнить элементы списка друг с другом в цикле и больший элемент
разделить на меньший. 
Но при этом не присваивать имена каждому элементу списка.

---

Мой код не дает сделать этого:

```
for i in list:  
     if list[i] > list[i + 1]:  
     a = (list[i] / list[i + 1] ) 
     else:  
         a = (list[i + 1] / list[i] ) 
     print(a)
```

**`Пользоваться библиотеками нельзя.`**

Выдает исключение:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not
>
> float`

Comment: У вас же скобки не закрыты

Comment: Исправил,спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = [220.32, 205.1, 204.6, 203.2, 203.75, 203.25, 203.75, 203.5]

[ [myList[i-1]/myList[i] if myList[i-1]>myList[i] else myList[i]/myList[i-1]] for i in range(1, len(myList)) ]

[[1.0742077035592394], [1.0024437927663734], [1.0068897637795275], [1.0027066929133859], [1.002460024600246], [1.002460024600246], [1.0012285012285012]]
```

или так:

```
for i in range(1, len(myList)):
    if myList[i-1]>myList[i]:
        a = myList[i-1]/myList[i]
    else:
        a = myList[i]/myList[i-1]
    print(a)


1.0742077035592394
1.0024437927663734
1.0068897637795275
1.0027066929133859
1.002460024600246
1.002460024600246
1.0012285012285012
```

Comment: Мне не нужно импортировать библиотеки,код должен быть без их использования

Comment: @SinCap Пожалуйста, без импорта )

Comment: Всё как бы ПОЧТИ тоже самое,только плюс с минусом попутал в сравнении и объект,который будет обрабатывать цикл не совсем верно указал.Плохо разобрался в похожих алгоритмах.Посоветуете может что-то?

Comment: @SinCap  посмотрите второй вариант, наверное вам будет понятнее. Хотя это одно и то же.

Comment: Второй вариант и сам понимаю.Хочу более подробней разобраться именно почему так : range(1, len(myList)) и [i-1] .Мне не понятен сам этот алгоритм.Где(ресурс,книга) можно разобраться в этом?Почему итерация начинается не с 0-го эл-та,а с первого? А здесь ([i -1])вообще не включен последний элемент списка!

Comment: @SinCap Мы сравниваем прочитанный элемент списка с предыдущим, поэтому начинае с индекса 1, а не 0.  Вот и все.

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен за разъяснение,безумно помогли  с решением,спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
#  a = [((a / b) if (a > b) else (b / a)) for (a, b) in zip(myList, myList[1:])]
# import operator, itertools
# a = list(itertools.starmap(operator.truediv, map(reversed, map(sorted, zip(myList, myList[1:])))))

myList = [220.32, 205.1, 204.6, 203.2, 203.75, 203.25, 203.75, 203.5]

a = list(next(i)/next(i) for i in map(iter, map(reversed, map(sorted, zip(myList, myList[1:])))))
print(a)  # [1.0742077035592394, 1.0024437927663734, 1.0068897637795275, 1.0027066929133859, 1.002460024600246, 1.002460024600246, 1.0012285012285012]
```

Comment: Автор указал, что нельзя пользоваться библиотеками